How to use ParseIntPipe in nest js so it accepts optional values?
I Have the following line of code in nest js, but it does not work as expected.
Even though the optional parameter is set to true, not sending the Year query param fails because of validation.
@Query('Year', new ParseIntPipe({ optional: true })) yearQ: number | undefined,

How can I make the query param optional, but to keep the validation if the Year param is defined?

For you to use ParseIntPipe in an optional param you will need to define a default value:
@Query('Year', new ParseIntPipe({ optional: true })) yearQ: number = 2024

This should work
